# Replacing a damaged SATA cable on a Lenovo Thinkpad T560

Tags: laptop, sata, thinkpad

I am interested in buying a Lenovo Thinkpad T560. However, the product I am interested in is listed as having a damaged SATA cable. I found [this product](https://www.ebay.com/itm/SATA-HDD-CABLE-Lenovo-Thinkpad-T560-T460-450-06D02-0001-00UR860-US-TOP/302815318220) on ebay. I am wondering how risky or difficult it is to connect this cable to the motherboard? Does the cable snap into place or does it have to be soldered?

Comment: While fixing the cable maybe quite simple, I'd be worried about HOW it got damaged, it's not the kind of thing you get from simply dropping a device and may indicate there's a lot more damage (or abuse the machine has faced) which isn't so visible.

Comment: @djsmiley2k-CoW You helped me to step back and think more broadly about the decision. It seems likely that someone was rough when having the lid open for that cable to be damaged. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm not saying it's a good idea or bad - I honestly  don't know and without knowledge of that cable/laptop layout I can't concider how it'd become damaged. Some internal things on laptops are very easily damaged, but seem to be so well protected that it's supprising they ever get damaged - others might be indicators of abuse to a machine, whichj should be avoided.

Comment: I ended up buying a different product than the one in question here with no damage but at $13 more expensive overall. 
It is for the same line of reasoning that I did not consider buying one with a cracked case, which basically means that it was dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering how risky or difficult it is to connect this cable to the motherboard?

Part of the answer depends on your skill with a screw-driver and your hand/eye coordination.

The cable *should* slide into a connector in the motherboard. The photos show a "tang" with some kind of black strap (Tape? Velcro?). The tang will slide into a slot on the motherboard.